# How to give diffrent height to each cards in bootstrap on hover

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap cards. I have put hover effects on the cards. On hovering over a larger device, it enlarges the rest of the cards as well. It works fine in smaller device. I want that on hover, only the card that is hovered should be bigger and the rest remain the same.
I have given snippet try this snippet in full screen than you will get my problem clearly.

```css
.card{
            cursor: pointer;
            transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
        }
        .content{
            max-height: 0;
            transition: max-height 0.15s ease-out;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        .content .copy{
            max-height: 0;
            transition: max-height 0.15s ease-out;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .card-footer{
            max-height: 0;
            transition: max-height 0.15s ease-out;
            overflow: hidden;
            border:none !important;
        }
        .card-header{
            display: block;
            border:none !important;
            padding-top: 20px;
            padding-bottom: 20px;
            transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
            transition: border 0.15s ease-out;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        /* adding hover */
        .card:hover{
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgb(86 82 90 / 35%) !important;
        }
        .card:hover .content{
            max-height: 500px;
            transition: max-height 0.25s ease-in;
        }

        .card:hover .copy{
            max-height: 500px;
            transition: max-height 0.25s ease-in;
        }
        .card:hover .card-footer{
            max-height: 500px;
            transition: max-height 0.25s ease-in;
            border-top: 1px solid #d7dae3;
        }

        .card:hover .card-header{
            display: block;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #d7dae3;
            transition: border 0.25s ease-in;
        }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xl-4">
                        <div class="card shadow-sm p-4">
                            <div class="card-header p-0 text-center">
                                <h2 class="title">Card 1</h2>
                            </div>
                            <div class="content text-break p-2">
                                <p class="copy">card-1 description</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-footer text-left p-0">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary m-3">View</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- end cards -->
                    <div class="col-xl-4">
                        <div class="card shadow-sm p-4">
                            <div class="card-header p-0 text-center">
                                <h2 class="title">Card 1</h2>
                            </div>
                            <div class="content text-break p-2">
                                <p class="copy">card-1 description</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-footer text-left p-0">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary m-3">View</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- end cards -->
                    <div class="col-xl-4">
                        <div class="card shadow-sm p-4">
                            <div class="card-header p-0 text-center">
                                <h2 class="title">Card 1</h2>
                            </div>
                            <div class="content text-break p-2">
                                <p class="copy">card-1 description</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-footer text-left p-0">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary m-3">View</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- end cards -->
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The snippet is working fine now.**

Only you and other IOS users can see this problem because you are entering only with IOS, it has happened to me before. I encountered it especially in the images that I aligned with flexbox.

> Because IOS and Windows flexbox defaults may differ in some cases.

For example, according to IOS the heights of the boxes should be aligned and the others should emulate and fill the highest box.

But this is not the case on Android and Windows. They leave the boxes as is. Roughly, [we could call it `flex-start`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/align-items/).

In this case we cannot rely on the defaults to behave typical of every device type. So we have to declare it how we want it to behave when the height changes.

There is always a class when it comes to Bootstrap. The class you should use.

```css
.align-items-start
```

Before forgetting, the element you need to place this class is exactly as follows.

```css
<div class="row align-items-start">
```

> Of course, please be understanding in case this doesn't work as it's purely hypothetical. Because the example you added is working correctly now.

Comment: Hello @BOZ it's not fixed my problem but thanks for your response and giving me some information